# Substituting a multi-line pattern in an HTML file

Tags: linux, sed, find-and-replace

I have a series of HTML files that contain two lines like this:

```
<body>
<h1>Title</h1><p>
<a href="url">Description</a><br>
```

I want to replace this text with something else using a bash script. I'm trying

```
sed -i -r 's/<h1>Title.*?$\/^.*?<br>/Replacement text/1' filename.html
```

but it is not working. I'm suspecting it is getting stuck on the new line and not knowing how to go around the problem.

Any help appreciated. Feel free to suggest other Linux tools other than `sed` as long as it works!

Comment: Do you really need `sed` for this? `sed` reads line-by-line, so replacing multi-line text is a little tedious there.

Comment: I don't have to use sed. I'm open to other linux commands.

Comment: yeah a pattern crossing multiple lines may be an issue for sed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use Perl for this:

```
perl -0pe 's/<h1>Title.*\n.*<br>/replacement/' filename.html
```

Here, `-0` makes Perl split records on the `NUL` character instead of reading line-by-line, which is the default when using the `-p` option.

With Perl regular expressions you need `.*`  to match any character multiple times, and you match the newline with `\n`.

Example:

```
$ echo '<body>
<h1>Title</h1><p>
<a href="url">Description</a><br>' | perl -0pe 's/<h1>Title.*\n.*<br>/replacement/'
<body>
replacement
```

Comment: And don't forget, [never use regular expressions to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936)! :)

Comment: This is *almost* good. I added a ? after the two .* to disable greediness. Is it possible to make the command modify the file instead of outputting to STDOUT?

Comment: @ToDo Perl can do in-place editing with the `-i` option, so run `perl -0p -i~ -e 's/…/…/'` to have it edit the original file, creating a backup copy with `~` as suffix. Or, to replace without backup file, call `perl -0pi -e …`.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` cannot match more than one line directly. When multiline pattern is needed, reach for a more powerful tool like Perl:

```
perl -i~ -ne 'if (/^<h1>Title/) {
                  $n = <>;
                  if ($n =~ /<br>$/) { print "Replacement\n" }
                  else { print "$_$n" }
              } else { print }'
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with sed.

```
sed -nf repl.sed filename.html
```

where `repl.sed` contains:

```
# Must have one line loaded up before branching to rep.
# Processing will start this way.
:rep
# Load extra line into pattern space
N
# Test for title
/<h1>.*<\/h1><p>\n<a href=".*">.*<\/a><br>/{
  #Substitute and print
  s/<h1>\(.*\)<\/h1><p>\n<a href=".*">.*<\/a><br>/Title: \1/p
  #append next line without cycling
  N
  # everything but the last line
  s/.*\n\([.\n]*\)/\1/
  #test for last line
  ${
    p
    # this will effectively end the program
    n
  }
  b rep
}
${
  # will print pattern space (both lines)
  p
  # this will effectively end the program
  n
}
#Print first line in pattern space
P;
#Remove first line in pattern space with newline
s/.*\n\([.\n]*\)/\1/
b rep
```

See [Working with Multiple Lines](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51)